# Race conditions on directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have a directive that calculates the height and distance from the top of the window of an element that is passed in as an id to an attribute. The issue I'm running into is that I have several of these directives running (on elements that are attached to the same directive), and I'm running into a race condition where some of the directives that are lower down in the DOM are running before the ones that are higher up for whatever reason.

Is there a way I can make the bottom ones wait for the ones higher up via a promise or something? If so, how would I implement that? Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: are these part of an `ng-repeat`? Showing some code would help and is standard practice around here

Comment: Are your 'Lower down in the DOM' directives **nested** directives or are they siblings?

Comment: Also, Angular doesn't compile sibling directives asyncronously, it compiles them in order - from what you describe, unless you are generating your directives dynamically from the results of an async request you're making, it seems unlikely that you're facing a "race condition."

Comment: @charlietfl None of them are in an ng-repeat.

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney They are not siblings. They all have different parents. What else do you think it could be?

Comment: I think it could be that we need to see some code - show us your HTML markup and the directive definition

Comment: Also, how are you binding the data to your view, are you making async requests to get the data? Or is it all static data?

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney It's a pretty complex app. Lots of partials and directives making up the view. I'll see if I can pastebin a simplified HTML view to give you an example. All of the data is pulled in from requests. No static info.

Comment: Yeah, do what you can to give a snippet or maybe point us to a URL where we can see what's going on. My guess is that the requests pulling in the data are the reason your directives are loading at various times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want code to be executed by your directive in the descending order (higer in the DOM comes first), you should either put that code in your directive's `controller`, or `preLink` methods.

The default `link` method is a shortcut to `postLink` which is executed in a ascending order.

That being said, I don't know your code so I am just making a guess, but it sounds like a service would be more appropriate than a directive, unless the calcul you're doing is done directly in that directive element, in which case using `$element` should be enough. But you should probably not pass an `id` or selector to a directive.